# AssertionError when using a test client in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use the following code in my client to check the response:

```
 assert.strictEqual(data,{'status':'ok','message':'tweet received'});
```

This is the code I wrote when sending the message:

```
 res.send({status:'ok',message:'tweet recieved'});
```

This is the error I got:

```
 assert.js:92
 throw new assert.AssertionError({
    ^
 AssertionError: "{\n  \"status\": \"ok\",\n  \"message\": \"tweet recieved\"\n}" === {"status":"ok","message":"tweet received"}
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/anr/Desktop/node js/mvc/ntwittertest.js:22:10)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:920:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response what you have got, is in String format. You might have to do `JSON.parse` to get the JavaScript object.

```
JSON.parse(data)
```

But, to compare two objects you might want to do `JSON.stringify` on both of them and compare them as strings.

```
JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data)) === JSON.stringify(other_object)
```

Even this method has its own issues. Strict comparing two objects will be successful only if both the expressions point to the same object. For example,

```
var obj1 = {};
var obj2 = {};
var obj3 = obj1;
console.log(obj1 === obj2);
console.log(obj1 === obj3);
```

Even though `obj1` and `obj2` are identical, they are not the same. So, it will return `false`. But in the second case, they both refer to the same object. That is why it returns `true`.

Read about Object comparison, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) to get more information.

I would recommend, parsing the JSON string to a valid JavaScript object and then do **member level comparison.**

Comment: Just using JSON.parse would return false as they are two different objects and cannot be strictly equal.A member level comparision would be better I guess.

Comment: @user2309862 Yup :) Thats what I have recommended in my answer :)